# Inject higher parent component (not direct parent) to child in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I need to inject a parent component that is not a direct parent.

`@Host()` decorator allows to inject only direct parent component.

Real example - menu and menu item component. I want to place menu on page

```
<menu [name]="'smth'">
  <auth-logout></auth-logout>
  <!-- ... other menu items -->
</menu>
```

`name` input calls actions on menu (e.x. toggle) through menu service.
Any menu item child component can contain `menu-item` component

```
<menu-item (itemClick)="logout()">
  LOGOUT
</menu-item>
```

and `menu-item` template

```
<div class="menu-item"    
     (click)="onClick()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ArQZYZsHQgn6I2eK3AZd

I want to inject `menu` component into `menu-item` to call `close()` method on `menu-item` click event. `auth-logout` should not know anything about this menu-components interaction and i dont want to duplicate close logic in each menu item.

Why not wrap like so?

```
<menu>
  <menu-item>
    <auth-logout></auth-logout>
  </menu-item>
</menu>
```

Because `menu-item` block has some styles that breaks proper clicking on child component (e.x. padding) and it's hard to automatically close menu on click (requires to pass menu name to each component like `auth-logout` or add output in this components)

Why not to use service call from `menu-item`?
Because it requires to pass menu name through each menu item (like `auth-logout`) and down to `menu-item`, but components like `auth-logout` should not know anything about this interactions or menu-names or anything else.

One more example - items list with some item sub-component, that listens to list changes event (Subject at list component) and do some stuff on emit(e.x. item image `src` update by adding new timestamp param to reset caching and update image). Passing list name to interact via service is too complex due to deep component nesting (name is required due to different lists on a page)

This cases works well in ng1 with `require` property that allows to inject any higher level parent to a component

**Update:**

Example above can be fixed via removing `@Host()` and adding missed `private` in constructor inject (thx @yurzui).
But real issue are more complex and this solution does not help. Here is updated plnkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/p7Vd4FRpHPRtyEuL6pEZ

The difference is added `header-menu` component that has this template

```
<menu>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</menu>
```

And injection `menu` into `menu-item` component does not work with this components nesting

```
header-menu
  menu
    auth-logout
      menu-item
```

**Update/Answer:**
Final case with `header-menu` falls with this issue github.com/angular/angular/issues/5126 and this does not support yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `@Host()` decorator and don't forget about `private`. Otherwise `this.menuComponent` will always be `undefined` without `private` modification.

```
constructor (@Optional() private menuComponent: MenuComponent)
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0o8fw8w6oEMiRUVe2NpX?p=preview)**

Comment: hm, it's strange that i've missed `private`. Y'r right, it works with my example, but this does not work in real app and i debugged a bit more and add an Update to question.

Comment: got answer in angular gitter: this case does not support now - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5126

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aalkKjjuH2h2CElu0oPn?p=preview).
This is one way of passing an instance down: use the [Template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).
Injection is too complicated for me.

In app.component.html:

```
<menu #mm><!-- use whatever name after # -->
  <auth-logout [menu]='mm'></auth-logout>
</menu>
```

In auth-logout.component.html:

```
<menu-item (itemClick)="logout()" [menu]="menu">
  LOGOUT
</menu-item>
```

In auth-logout.component.ts:

```
@Input() menu: MenuComponent;
```

In menu-item.component.ts:

```
@Input() menu: MenuComponent;
```

The `#mm`(the instance of MenuComponent) will be passed down to auth-logout as `menu`, then down to menu-item also as `menu`, then you can call `menu.close()` in menu-item.